# Azure Devops Boards - can we block task from done if there isn't any test attatched?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards, azure-task-groups

We are trying to implement a new method for our QA team.
I have looked around the setting but couldn't find an answer:

- Is it possible to prevent them from dragging the task to 'Done' if they haven't added a test case into it?
- On the same logic - can we block the 'committed' column from them if they haven't added a bug to the task?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no build-in feature to help you achieve this directly.

Here is a work around for your demand:

Create a new filed named "TestCaseLinked"

[image]

Every time a Test Case is linked to the task WIT, you need to manually put a value into this field. And use the WIT rule to check the value when changing the WIT status to "Done"

[image]

[image]

[image]